# In scala cats 2.9.x, is it possible to flatMap a Set?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, flatmap

When I try to rewrite some of my libraries in scala cats, I found that not all operators are supported, e.g. it is very common to flatMap a Set in native Scala:

```
val v: Set[Int] = ???
v.flatMap(v => Set(v, v*2))
```

But it is not possible using cats:

```
  def flatMap2[F[_]](vs: F[Int])(
      implicit
      isFlatMappable: FlatMap[F],
      canConvert: Factory[Int, F[Int]]
  ): F[Int] = {
    isFlatMappable.flatMap(vs)(v => canConvert.fromSpecific(Set(v, v * 2)))
  }

  flatMap2(Set(1, 2, 3))

// yield error: [Error] /xxx:yyy/zzz : could not find implicit value for parameter isFlatMappable: cats.FlatMap[scala.collection.immutable.Set]
```

Why is it not working? What should be done to fix it?

Comment: TL;DR; `Set` is not a `Functor` but the reasons for that are always hard to explain and many people would say they are not really useful in practice. **allyecats** does provide the `Monad` and `Traverse` instances for `Set` - BTW, I wonder if opening a new issue in the **cats** repo today would lead to their inclusion again.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I doubt they did. @tribbloid the rationale is that instances in cats-core have to follow certain intuitions (some would call them laws, other contracts) and `Set` does not implement them - it only implements an interface without the rules associated with it, so it is assumed that whoever want's to use it is aware that there might be surprises. Such instances end up in alleycats.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok well, all examples I can find of why `Functor[Set]` is lawless require some other violations, like a faulty `equals`; in a similar sense, I can argue that `list.map(println)` is not RT; but the problem is not `map` but `println` - Note that similar arguments have been made with regard of the instances for `Future` where in theory they are fine for pure computations, yet we all know they are used for side-effects; also `Future` only matters in concurrency otherwise is like an `Id` - Yet, the `Future` instances were not removed; and, IMHO, `Functor[Set]` is even more pragmatic

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `could not find implicit value for parameter e: cats.Functor[Set]`. I only found the `UnorderedTraverse` instance for Set in cats-core

Comment: @tribbloid That is exactly what I said, there is no such instance in **cats**; **alleycats** remains; but as a module, what was deprecated the different repository: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/tree/main/alleycats-core

Comment: For functor to be lawful, it has to follow functor law: `fa.map(f).map(g) == f.map(f andThen g)`. The fact that `Set` removes duplicates may prevent you from having the same results here. You can argue that these f and g may be maliciously defined to break it, but that's the idea of laws/contracts - you don't have to worry about the edge cases, because you eliminated them by design. If you cannot, you want to know and address than explicitly rather than hope that you remember to write unit test for it which will catch such case after refactor which shouldn't have changed the behavior but did.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok spot on.